# iPhone follow a user on twitter programmatically

Tags: iphone, ipad, twitter, sharekit, twitter-follow

I want to follow a twitter user on a button click. I used the share kit follow me method using oauth. But always I am getting this error.

> {"error":"Could not authenticate with
>   OAuth.","request":"/1/friendships/create/priyankav89.json"}

Then I tried to implement it myself

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1/friendships/create.json"];
NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dict setObject:@"871252998" forKey:@"user_id"];
[dict setObject:@"true" forKey:@"follow"];
[dict setObject:@"KXL0jFLJY6RI4lszOz8r5w" forKey:@"consumer"];
NSString *jsonRepresentation=[dict JSONString];
NSLog(@"jsonRepresentation = %@",jsonRepresentation);
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:3];
NSData *postData=[NSData dataWithBytes:jsonRepresentation.UTF8String length:[jsonRepresentation length]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error=nil;
NSData *responseData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSLog(@"respon = %s",responseData.bytes);
```

still I am getting the same error.

I searched a lot. Still no use. I don't want to load the url in a UIWebView or in safari. I want to support the app from ios4. So ios5 built-in twitter app cannot be used.

Comment: Are you using the sharekit use or not?

Comment: I tried the share kit follow me method for twitter. But its not working. I am using share kit for sharing text which is working perfect.

Comment: In short what you want to do on twitter share?

Comment: Check if you are going through authentication first? Also, check if Oauth is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. In share kit follow me method they are not calling the authorization method before following. So we want to call authorize before login and save the access token.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know how to tweet using the twitter integrated to the iOS, you can simply tweet "follow "